# Equivalence of two finite dimensionality conditions

Tags: linear-algebra

We must show that the following are equivalent. Note that $V$ is a vector space:

**1)** there exists a finite subset of $V$ which spans $V$

**2)** A linearly independent subset of $V$ is finite

Should I use Zorn's Lemma?

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of basis or dimension? Do you know the exchange theorem by Steinitz? (sorry, not entirely sure about the English name of that one...)

Comment: Do you mean _every_ linearly independent subset of $V$ is finite?

Comment: $2$ implies $1$ is false, since *every* non-trivial vector space  over $\mathbb R$ has an element $a \neq 0$ , which shows that $\{ a\}$ is linearly independent. However, some of  these are infinite dimensional, so the first condition doesn't apply. There is an adjustment to be made in the question.

Comment: @Bemte I've more often seen it called ["lemma"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz_exchange_lemma) than "theorem" in English, but as long as your label is a variant of "Steinitz exchange (lemma|theorem)" it's entirely correct.

Comment: It suffices in this case to show that given a linearly dependent set, one may remove one of the vectors without changing the span.

Answer (score 0):

One direction is easy: if there does not exist any finite spanning set, then one can inductively choose an infinite linearly independent sequence of vectors by, starting from the empty sequence, repeatedly adding a vector not in the span of the previous ones (which must exist since the previous ones being finite in number cannot span all of $V$).

For the other direction it helps to know that every finite linear homogeneous system of equations with *more unknowns* than equations has a nontrivial solution; this is not hard to show by induction on the number of equations, and I will assume this known.

Suppose $V$ is spanned by $n$ vectors $s_1,\ldots,s_n$ and let $v_1,\ldots,v_m\in V$ be any family of $m$ vectors with $m>n$; we shall prove that $v_1,\ldots,v_m$ are always linearly dependent, whence *a fortiori* no infinite family can be linearly independent. Let $f:K^n\to V$ be the map $(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)\mapsto\alpha_1s_1+\ldots+\alpha_ns_n$; the fact that the $s_i$ spans $V$ means that $f$ is surjective. So in particular there exist $w_1,\ldots,w_m\in K^n$ (not necessarily unique) such that $f(w_i)=v_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,m$. Similarly to $f$, define $g:K^m\to K^n$ to be the map $(x_1,\ldots,x_m)\mapsto x_1w_1+\ldots+x_mw_m$; then clearly we have that $g\circ f:K^m\to V$ maps $(x_1,\ldots,x_m)\mapsto x_1v_1+\ldots+x_mv_m\in V$. Finding a linear dependence between the vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_m$ amounts to finding a nonzero $m$-tuple $(x_1,\ldots,x_m)\in\ker(g\circ f)$, because that membership means that $x_1v_1+\ldots+x_mv_m=0$. We shall in fact find a nonzero $m$-tuple $(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_m)\in\ker(g)$, which suffices since $\ker(g)\subseteq\ker(g\circ f)$. But the condition $(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_m)\in\ker(g)$ amounts to a linear homogeneous system of $n$ equations (one for each coordinate in $K^n$) in $m$ unknowns $x_1,\ldots,x_m$. We observed that such a system always has a nontrivial (i.e., nonzero) solution, which completes the proof.